# Swift 4 switch statement comparing multiple values, using greater than or less than

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I know in Swift I can do a simple Swift switch statement to compare computed values with a single variable:

```
let distanceTravelled = -145.1
switch distanceTravelled {
case _ where distanceTravelled < 15:
    print("You travelled the right distance")
default:
    print("Sad face")
}
```

But I want to be able to set up a matrix of comparisons using tuples, something like this:

```
let distanceTravelled = -145.1,
    origin = 2

switch (origin, distanceTravelled) {
case (2, _ where distanceTravelled < 15):
    print("You travelled the right distance")
default:
    print("Sad face")
}
```

But this doesn't compile, complaining that `expected ',' separator` and `expected expression in list of expressions`.

Obviously this is syntactically incorrect, but shouldn't it work given that this works?

```
switch (2, -145.1) {
case (2, _):
    print("You travelled the right distance")
default:
    print("Sad face")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Aha! Found the answer in the good ol' [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html). I wasn't thinking of this in terms of the condition being a tuple.

```
switch (origin, distanceTravelled) {
case let (_, d) where d < 15:
    print("You travelled the right distance")
default:
    print("Sad face")
}
```

For my actual use case, this got a little weirder because I was comparing an `enum` property for origin, but it worked out:

```
let absOriginDistanceFromDefault = abs(defaultDividerPosition - viewDividerOrigin)

switch (splitViewOrigin, distanceTravelled) {
case let (.defaultPosition, d) where d < -100:
    return .shouldMoveToTopView
case let (.defaultPosition, d) where d > 100:
    return .shouldMoveToBottomView
case (.topView, _) where currentDividerPosition - defaultDividerPosition < -100:
    return .shouldMoveToBottomView
case (.topView, _) where abs(distanceTravelled) > absOriginDistanceFromDefault * 0.5 && currentDividerPosition < self.view.bounds.height:
    return .shouldMoveToDefaultPosition
case (.bottomView, _) where currentDividerPosition - defaultDividerPosition > 100:
    return .shouldMoveToTopView
case (.bottomView, _) where abs(distanceTravelled) > absOriginDistanceFromDefault * 0.3 && currentDividerPosition > 0:
    return .shouldMoveToDefaultPosition
default:
    return .shouldReturnToOrigin
}
```

And oddly enough, in simplifying it further, it turns out I don't even need to declare variables in the first two checks at all:

```
let absOriginDistanceFromDefault = abs(defaultDividerPosition - viewDividerOrigin)

switch (splitViewOrigin, distanceTravelled) {
case (.defaultPosition, _) where distanceTravelled < -100,
     (.bottomView, _) where currentDividerPosition - defaultDividerPosition > 100:
    return .shouldMoveToTopView
case (.defaultPosition, _) where distanceTravelled > 100,
     (.topView, _) where currentDividerPosition - defaultDividerPosition < -100:
    return .shouldMoveToBottomView
case (.topView, _) where abs(distanceTravelled) > absOriginDistanceFromDefault * 0.5 && currentDividerPosition < maxHeight,
     (.bottomView, _) where abs(distanceTravelled) > absOriginDistanceFromDefault * 0.3 && currentDividerPosition > 0:
    return .shouldMoveToDefaultPosition
default:
    return .shouldReturnToOrigin
}
```